# bootstrap4 flex justify-content:justify-content-between issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using **bootstrap4** flex utilities classes for flex layout. I am not able to apply `justify-content-between` css in the **number(01)** and **Add Plan** button below means I want the *number(01)* to left align and *Add Plan* button to right align.

***Also is this a good idea to use bootstrap4 flex utilities classes or just use our own classes because I have a doubt that it will create a problem in responsive layout?***

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.day-block {
  flex-basis: 49%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: .5%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #e4e4e4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #e4e4e4;
  min-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.day-block p {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="day-block">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-self-start">
      <div class="day-number">01</div>
      <button class="btn-add-plan">+ Add Plan</button>
    </div>
    <div class="align-self-end">
      <div class="added-plan-wrap">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It actually did apply `justify-content-between`, the problem is your div's width. Try to inscrease `width` and you will see.

Comment: @MinhDuc but why div is not taking 100% width?

Comment: Because your parent div `day-block` is using `flex` display so all the flex items inside it will just wrap its content rather than take the full width

Comment: @MinhDuc but after removing the flex in `day-block` div, `align-self-end` in not working in the below div. I don't think giving width:100% to the div is a genuine solution.

Comment: I saw you use `flex-basis`. Why don't you try that instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `day-block` class make the `<div class="day-block">` element a flex row container.

That makes the `<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-self-start">` element a flex row item, and a flex row item's default `flex` shorthand property is `0 1 auto`, which mean it is sized by its content, hence the `justify-content-between` has no effect.

For `justify-content-between` to have an effect, add e.g. the built in `col` class, which change the `flex-grow` to `1`, and with that make the flex row item fill its parent's width.

*Note, since `col` also has padding, I added a custom class to remove it.*

Stack snippet

```css
.day-block {
  flex-basis: 49%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: .5%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #e4e4e4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #e4e4e4;
  min-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.day-block .col {
  padding: 0;            /*  if you don't want padding, keep this rule  */
}

.day-block p {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="day-block">

 <!-- added here ⇩ -->
    <div class="col d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-self-start">

      <div class="day-number">01</div>
      <button class="btn-add-plan">+ Add Plan</button>
    </div>
    <div class="align-self-end">
      <div class="added-plan-wrap">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

---

An alternative to the `col` (since it has padding's), could be a custom `flex-grow` class:

```
.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.day-block {
  flex-basis: 49%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: .5%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #e4e4e4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #e4e4e4;
  min-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.day-block p {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="day-block">

    <!-- added here ⇩ -->
    <div class="flex-grow d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-self-start">

      <div class="day-number">01</div>
      <button class="btn-add-plan">+ Add Plan</button>
    </div>
    <div class="align-self-end">
      <div class="added-plan-wrap">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
  <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but applying `col` class giving me extra paddings. So should I apply also `no-gutters` class to it or any other solution

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt In my answer I focused on showing what caused it to not work. `no-gutters` reset margins, not paddings. As Bootstrap doesn't have a built-in `padding: 0` class, you could make a custom one, or create a custom `flex-grow` class instead of using the built-in `col`. Updated my answer with both options.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the bolded question: Yes, unlike Bootstrap 3, Bootstrap 4 allows you to get done almost anything you'll ever need using the native Bootstrap 4 classes alone without ever touching css.

Regarding the rest of the question:

The following code does exactly what you're asking for without any custom css:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                <div class="day-block">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-self-start">
                        <div class="day-number">01</div>
                        <button class="btn-add-plan">+ Add Plan</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="align-self-end">
                        <div class="added-plan-wrap">
                            <p class="mb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> <!-- class "mb" is margin bottom; choose a value between 0 and 5 -->
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
                <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
                <div class=" day-block d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the use of the `mb-3` class for margin bottom of the first paragraph.

Also note: The only thing I did is to use your code (inside a container-row-column structure) without your css. The alignment is exactly as you wish.